# Telegram bot with aws lambda and API gateway

Tags: json, amazon-web-services, aws-lambda, telebot

I am developing a telegram bot with python (telebot) , aws lambda and api gateway.

I have a problem in the lambda function and I can't understand why I have this kind of problem.

My lambda is this:

```py
import telebot
import datetime

TOKEN = 'xxx'

def lambda_handler(event, context):
   bot = telebot.TeleBot(TOKEN)
   # Extract the message key over payload's body
   message = json.loads(event['body'])
   print(message)
   
   # Split between three variables bellow
   chat_id = message['chat']['id'] # Chat ID will guide your chatbot reply 
   sender = message['from']['first_name'] # Sender's first name, registered by user's telegram app
   text = message['text'] # The message content
   
   if text.lower().strip() == "/time":
   
       current_time = datetime.strftime(datetime.now(), "%H:%M:%S")
       bot.send_message(chat_id, "Right now its {} UTC.".format(current_time))
       
   else:
       pass
```

The error I get, running the test is this:

```json
Response
{
  "errorMessage": "'body'",
  "errorType": "KeyError",
  "stackTrace": [
    "  File \"/var/task/lambda_function.py\", line 10, in lambda_handler\n    message = json.loads(event['body'])\n"
  ]
}
```

The given json file:

```json
{
    "update_id": 0000000,
    "message": {
        "message_id": 000000,
        "from": {
            "id": 00000000,
            "is_bot": false,
            "first_name": "myname",
            "last_name": "mysurname",
            "username": "sursurname",
            "language_code": "it"
        },
        "chat": {
            "id": 000000,
            "first_name": "myname",
            "last_name": "mysurname",
            "username": "sursurname",
            "type": "private"
        },
        "date": 1654697178,
        "forward_from": {
            "id": 00000000,
            "is_bot": false,
            "first_name": "mysurname",
            "last_name": "mysurname",
            "username": "sursurname",
            "language_code": "it"
        },
        "forward_date": 0000000000,
        "text": "ciao"
    }
}
```

I cannot understand why it is not able to read the body in any way, maybe I am in the wrong library? Do you have any suggestions to help me with this?

Comment: Try `print(event)` as soon as you're in the handler - what do you get? Your error suggests there is no `body` in the event object so accessing it is causing a key error.

Answer (score 1):

`event['body']` is almost definitely not the correct key to access data passed through an event. The event passes information in a nested dictionary and you'll need to figure out how to drill down to the correct key.

Comment: I formatted json appropriately but now I get this error, **the JSON object must be str, bytes or bytearray, not dict**

Answer (score 0):

I solved it by doing this:

```
json_str = json.dumps(event)

resp = json.loads(json_str)
chat_id = resp['message']['chat']['id']
message_text = resp['message']['text']
message_chat_id = resp['message']['chat']['id']
message_username = resp['message']['from']['first_name']

bot = telebot.TeleBot(TOKEN)

bot.send_message(chat_id, "Hey, I understood this message!, hi {}".format(message_username))
```